# Why do my materials always look washed out?

Tags: texturing, materials

It seems that whenever I setup materials in the node editor it becomes washed out and pale and gutless compared to the image in the texture viewport. It's happening so often that I am always adding either a Mix Shader or MixRGB Darken node and even then the colour is not saturated or dark enough.

Please help I am losing my mind.

Texture on the left, material view on the right (same as in render view):

[image] [image]

Something must be fundamentally wrong with my simple node setup or some setting. Node setup uses albedo colour map, roughness map and Normal map:

[image: Node setup]

Comment: Ok so I checked the Shadeless shading option in the textured view and now it also looks washed out.

Comment: Unconnect all nodes and start connecting them one by one, should easy to spot when washing out starts showing

Comment: The texture- und material views are no accurate representations of your material. please only check your material settings when viewing in rendered view (there are some exceptions to this of course). see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60267/texture-look-lighter-in-material-view-than-in-render-view

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The image textures themselves are fine. I am evaluating the materials in the rendered view it's just that it looks similar to the material view in this case and I wanted to remove the effect of lighting which I've played with to no effect. That being said, I am beginning to think that the lighting is playing a bigger role here than I thought so I'll investigate.